# Passing cookies in nginx on subsequent request does not work

Tags: java, nginx, redirect, cookies

There are 2 urls used in Java app (nginx is used as reversed proxy) that may vary depending on if the user is logged in or not.

The urls are as follows:

- example.*.com (if the user is not logged in)
- my.example.*.com (if the user is logged in)

On the main page **(example.*.com)** there's a button that can be clicked only if the user is logged in. Normally, the path is **my.example.*.com** but when the user enters **example.*.com**  directly in URL address bar and clicks the button, the following happens:

1. First POST request that goes to **example.*.com** and redirects (307) the user.
2. Second POST request that makes a call to **my.example.*.com** and returns 403.

From what I could gather, the second request fails because there are no credentials passed.

To make the question complete, I include the both requests full info (I apologise in advance if there's influx of redundant info).

The 1st request:

```
General:

Request URL: https://example.*.com/subscribe?addressGuid=cef10ea9-3391-4e7d-95d8-973c7b969348
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 307 Temporary Redirect
Remote Address: *the IP*:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request Headers:

POST /subscribe?addressGuid=cef10ea9-3391-4e7d-95d8-973c7b969348 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru,ru-RU;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Cookie: *lots of cookies, including auth ones*
Host: example.*.com
Origin: https://example.*.com
Referer: https://example.*.com/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"

Response Headers:

HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Date: Mon, 26 Jun 2023 06:31:24 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://my.example.*.com/subscribe?addressGuid=cef10ea9-3391-4e7d-95d8-973c7b969348
Server: ""
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' http://webvisor.com https://webvisor.com
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=16070400
```

And the second one:

```
General:

Request URL:
https://my.example.*.com/subscribe?addressGuid=cef10ea9-3391-4e7d-95d8-973c7b969348
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request Headers:

POST /subscribe?addressGuid=cef10ea9-3391-4e7d-95d8-973c7b969348 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru,ru-RU;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: my.example.*.com
Origin: https://example.*.com
Referer: https://example.*.com/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"

Response Headers:

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Mon, 26 Jun 2023 06:31:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: route_rest=bcf61aa8605ad5d73b2d8d03430237d9; Path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=LyjOf6xIZmrC3rtmO58kWTfT; (*different from JSESSIONID in previous request*) Path=/subscribe
Unauthenticated: true
Server: ""
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' http://webvisor.com https://webvisor.com
Content-Encoding: gzip
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=16070400
```

To make sure that the problem has to do with cookies, I took the original request (the one that returns 307) and changed the path from just **example.*.com** to **my.example.*.com** in Postman. It worked and returned me 200.

What seems to be the problem? Is there a way to make nginx include cookies on subsequent request or is the problem has to do with something else?

Having revised nginx configuration file, found this only:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  my.example.*.com;
    server_tokens off;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    return       301 https://my.example.*.com$request_uri; 
}
```

But apparently, it has nothing to do with the problem and served for http to https proxying only